# Using an external Template in KnockoutJS

Tags: templates, knockout.js, external, knockout-templating

is it possible to use an external Template in KnockoutJS like this?

```
<script type="text/html" id="a_template" src="templates/a_template.html">
</script>
```

I've tried this solution but didn't get it working.

Comment: You can also check this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17073648/load-knockout-template-from-external-file-without-complex-engine. It discusses external templates for KnockoutJS without the use of 3rd party frameworks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could also look at:

https://github.com/ifandelse/Knockout.js-External-Template-Engine

Comment: Thanks, this looks pretty straight forward.

Comment: *In your HTML file, reference jQuery, jquery-tmpl (if you're using jquery templates), knockout.js, TrafficCop, infuser and the koExternalTemplateEngine.js file* - It doesn't seem very lightweight :)

Comment: You can also just reference koExternalTemplateEngine_all.js which includes the template engine, TrafficCop and infuser.  All three libraries were written by Jim, as he recognized that some of this functionality was useful outside of KO.

Answer (score 23):

You can use jquery to dynamically load html into a script element, and then execute knockout based on that.

```javascript
<script type="text/html" id="template_holder"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#template_holder').load('templates/a_template.html', function() {
  alert('Load was performed.');
  //knockout binding goes here
});</script>
```

Your knockout binding must be done in the callback function though, otherwise there's a chance that you'll be trying to bind before the page has loaded

*UPDATE* Here's an example I've coded on jsfiddle to demonstrate dynamic loading: http://jsfiddle.net/soniiic/2HxPp/

Comment: Thanks but i think the External Template Engine is a bit better 'cause it hides all the requests.

Comment: Ok :) but remember that it's still possible for the user to see requests: http://code.google.com/chrome/devtools/docs/network-files/network_panel.png

Comment: This is a good solution. Here is an example knockout binding of a div template placeholder:
ko.applyBindings(myViewModel, $('#template_holder')[0]);

Answer (score 4):

You can also use this Template bootstrapper for KO

Bootstrapper
https://github.com/AndersMalmgren/Knockout.Bootstrap

MVC WebAPI Demo
https://github.com/AndersMalmgren/Knockout.Bootstrap.Demo

It uses a Convention over configuration approuch using this lib
https://github.com/AndersMalmgren/Knockout.BindingConventions

Meaning it will automatically understand that *MyViewModel* should be matched to *MyView*

Its also prepared to work nicely in a SPA

Disclaimer: I'm the author behind the 3 libs mentioned above

Answer (score 3):

Here's a little function building off of soniiic's answer:

```
function loadExternalKnockoutTemplates(callback) {
    var sel = 'script[src][type="text/html"]:not([loaded])';
    $toload = $(sel);
    function oncomplete() {
        this.attr('loaded', true);
        var $not_loaded = $(sel);
        if(!$not_loaded.length) {
            callback();
        }
    }
    _.each($toload, function(elem) {
        var $elem = $(elem);
        $elem.load($elem.attr('src'), _.bind(oncomplete, $elem));

    });
}
```

This'll automatically load all knockout templates on your document, provided their src is set and their type is "text/html".  Pass in a callback to be notified when all templates loaded.  No idea what happens if any of them fails.

Example usage:

```
 <head>
    <script type="text/html" src="kot/template1.html" id="template1"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <script>
        $(function() {
            loadExternalKnockoutTemplates(function() {
                // Put your ready code here, like
                ko.applyBindings();
            });
        });


        function loadExternalKnockoutTemplates(callback) {
            var sel = 'script[src][type="text/html"]:not([loaded])';
            $toload = $(sel);
            function oncomplete() {
                this.attr('loaded', true);
                var $not_loaded = $(sel);
                if(!$not_loaded.length) {
                    callback();
                }
            }
            _.each($toload, function(elem) {
                var $elem = $(elem);
                $elem.load($elem.attr('src'), _.bind(oncomplete, $elem));

            });
        }
    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: Very clever but I will not upvote before you replace '_.bind(oncomplete,$elem)' with 'oncomplete.bind($elem)'
and
'_.each' with 'ko.utils.arrayForEach' ;-)
No need to add underscore just yet