# Knockoutjs and templates: How to inject a string template without involving the DOM?

Tags: jquery, knockout.js, jquery-templates, knockout-2.0

In Microsoft Tmpl, you can inject a string template like this (from jQuery [man pages](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.tmpl/)):

```
jQuery.tmpl( template [, data][, options]);
$.tmpl( "<li>${Name}</li>", { "Name" : "John Doe" }).appendTo( "#target" );
```

And you could get the template from the server with a simple jQuery.get() without involving the DOM.

Now I know there are projects out there like [Knockout.js-External-Template-Engine](https://github.com/ifandelse/Knockout.js-External-Template-Engine), but is there a way to pass Knockout a Javascript method (or string) representing the template without placing the template in the DOM (especially if you're using an external template engine?)  Something like `data-bind="template: {name:mymethod}"`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

RP Niemeyer covers this in one of [his blog posts](http://www.knockmeout.net/2011/10/ko-13-preview-part-3-template-sources.html)

And here is [his fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/3598P/).

Comment: @soniiic mentions a nice way too [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9480946/84424).  Both very nice ways of handling it.