# Load knockout template from external file without complex engine?

Tags: templates, knockout.js

I've found engines, plugins and functions to load external templates, but I'm wondering if there's a simpler way to do it.  Something like this?

templates.html

```
<script id="testTemplate" type="text/html">
 <div>this is a div</div>
</script>
```

index.html

```
<div id="templateContainer"></div>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
         $("#templateContainer").load("templates.html");
    }
</script>
```

Will this work?  Are there any "gotchas"?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Here's what I use to load a template file that contains a collection of templates:

```
var loadTemplateCollection = function(file, success) {
    $.get('templates/' + file + '.html', function(templates) {
        $('body').append('<div style="display:none">' + templates + '<\/div>');
        success();
    });
};
```

Here's an example where I use this function:

```
self.loadPage = function () {
    if (!self.isLoaded()) {
        loadTemplateCollection('uploadwizard', function() {
            self.isLoaded(true);
            self.uploadWizard();
        });
    }
}
```

Your view would look something like this (the `if` is important):

```
<div data-bind="template: {'if': isLoaded, name: 'uploadwizard', data: wizard}"></div>
```

Comment: And what does `templates` variable contains in `loadTemplateCollection`? Script elements?

Comment: They are `<textarea>` elements.

Answer (score 6):

This is what I am using to load the new page view.
I think it is pretty simple to use :

```
var template = 'template.html';
var targetID = 'container';
var partialVM = {data : 1};

var load = function (template, targetID, partialVM) {
    $.ajax(template, { async: false })
        .success(function (stream) {
            $('#' + targetID).html(stream);
            ko.applyBindings(partialVM, document.getElementById(targetID));
        }
    );
};
```

But in my html templates I didn't have the script element, just a simple div as root element.

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 3):

I created  a new binding to load html from url and apply binding on it

```
ko.bindingHandlers.htmlUrl = {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext) {
        $(element).load(valueAccessor(), function () {
            $(element).children().each(function (index, child) {
                ko.applyBindings(bindingContext.$data, child);
            });
        });
    },
    update: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext) {

    }
};
```

usage

```
        <div data-bind="htmlUrl : <url>">


        </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I've finally been able to piece together a lazy template loader with the help of binding handlers. Wanted to share.

Lazy loader

```
markupLoader = {
    templateDictionary: {},
    loadMarkup: function (element, value, bindingContext) {
        if (!this.templateDictionary[value]) {
            this.templateDictionary[value] = $.get(value);
        }
        this.templateDictionary[value].done(function (template) {
            $(element).html(template);
            $(element).children().each(function (index, child) {
                ko.applyBindings(bindingContext, child);
            });
        });
    }
};
```

Binding handler

```
ko.bindingHandlers.htmlUrl = {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext) {
        let value = ko.unwrap(valueAccessor());
        markupLoader.loadMarkup(element, value, bindingContext);
        return { controlsDescendantBindings: true };
    }
};
```

Comment: Thanks! You the Best.