# Is there something similar to ng-include in Knockoutjs like in Angularjs

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, knockout.js

I have to include a html file inside a WebPage (Another HTML ) and I can do it effectively using AngularJs ng-include.

```
<div ng-include="'storage/html/storageResources.html'"></div>
```

I now have a requirement where I need to achieve the same using KnockoutJs and not Angular.
Is there something similar in KnockoutJs that I can make use of to include a html page inside another one?

Comment: I'm afraid there is no native way to do this with Knockout. You will find workarounds here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9480697/using-an-external-template-in-knockoutjs

Comment: Have you looked at [component loaders](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/component-loaders.html) ([especially this example](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/component-loaders.html#example-2-a-component-loader-that-loads-external-files-using-custom-code))?

Comment: I am trying to use the JQuery s
       <script type="text/javascript">
  $('#template_holder').load('templates/a_template.html', 
                 function() {
  alert('Load was performed.');
  //knockout binding goes here
  });</script>

But how I make use of observables inside the a_template.html file  ??